# Ошибка в программе mac changer на python

Tags: python, linux

Вот сам код:

```
import subprocess
import optparse



def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="interface to change its Mac adress")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="New mac adress")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("Please specify an interface, use --help for more info.")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("Please specify a new mac, use --help for more info.")
    return options

def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    print("[+] Changing mac adress for" + interface + "to" + new_mac)
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])

options = get_arguments()
ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
print(options.interface)
```

Код ошибки:

```
/root/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python /root/PycharmProjects/test/test.py
Usage: test.py [options]

test.py: error: Please specify an interface, use --help for more info.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Покажите мне готовое решение пожалуйсто, а то могу так и не понять)

Comment: Судя по ошибке, запускать программу нужно примерно так: `python test.py -i eth0 -m "aa:aa:aa:aa"`

Comment: Понял, значит программа запускается только из консоли. Я сейчас работаю по урокам и у автора программа после выполнения в консоли выдает текст комманды ifconfig и сам mac adress меняется. У меня же после выполнения в консоли просто выводит eth0 и все... Мак адресс не меняется. Вы случайно не можете подсказать в чем может быть причина?

Comment: скорее всего, из-за того что не хватает прав у текущего пользователя. Попробуйте `sudo python test.py -i eth0 -m "aa:aa:aa:aa"` либо из-под учетной записи `root`

Comment: Попробовал, ваш вариант - тоже самое выводит только eth0 и ничего не изменяется. eth0 выводит не параметры а просто текстом "eth0". В коде как я понимаю ошибок нет. Выполняю из под root и так, так что с правами все нормально...

Comment: может быть ваш сетевой интерфейс просто по-другому называется, а не eth0? попробуйте посмотреть в ifconfig

Comment: Нет, он называется eth0. Смотрел в ifconfig ...